# PHP braces { } replace <?php ?>?

Tags: php, syntax

I've seen in someones source code they load template.tpl and inside is ...`value="{$phcode}"`...
does `{$phcode}` replace `<?php $phcode ?>`

I don't find any reference in php manual.

Comment: I think you need to check your formatting.  Looks like your html got swallowed.  Use the `code` formatting tools.

Answer (score 10):

A .tpl file isn't a PHP file and isn't parsed by the PHP engine. I'd guess you're looking at a [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) template.

For the record, `<?php $phcode ?>` does nothing. You are probably thinking of either `<?php echo $phcode ?>` or `<?= $phcode ?>`, either of which is pretty close to exactly what Smarty does with that piece of code, yes.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely it is Smarty template.

More info here: http://www.smarty.net/syntax_comparison

Answer (score 1):

It's not PHP, it's using a templating language like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.basic.syntax).

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that's the [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) PHP templating engine. It can do stuff like that, it makes templating easier with the integrated php execution.

Answer (score 0):

No, `{}` doesn't replace `<?php ?>`, at least not as far as the PHP language is concerned.  It's possible that your template engine searches for things inside `{}` and then passes them to `eval()`.